# Detect nth term of binary sequence

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a binary sequence that follows a specific logic such that
it starts with `0` and

nth term = sequence of (n-1)th term + `0` + inverse(reverse(n-1)th term)

eg:

```
0
0 + 0 + 1
001 + 0 + 011
0010011 + 0 + 0011011
```

Here, I need to find out the nth term of the kth sequence.

My take:

I've written a recursive function to calculate the number of terms in k'th sequence

```
  public static long noOfElements(long elements){
     long answer;
     if(elements == 1)
        return 1;
     else
     answer = 1 + 2*noOfElements(elements-1);
     return answer;
}
```

After analysis, I found out the sequence follows a certain pattern, the k'th sequence can be broken down by half and switching the values of 0 and 1 I could keep track of the result.

So, My function below breaks the given sequence down to [0,0,1] recursively

```
public static long letsBegin(long reqd, long length){
    long mid = (length + 1)/2;
    if(length <= 3){
        return reqd;
    }else{
        if(reqd > mid){
            reqd = reqd - 2*(reqd-mid);
            switcher();                 //Switcher stores if the value is switched
            return letsBegin(reqd, mid);
        }else{
            return letsBegin(reqd, mid);
        }
    }
}
```

In the end I have index 1, 2 or 3 in [0,0,1] and I output the value accordingly.
The problem here is

1. It fails for some unknown case (Probably my logic's wrong).
2. The number of sequences can be upto 50, making number of elements = 1125899906842623 and hence, takes too long to output value (>2sec)
   What may have went wrong? Is my logic incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a case (when reqd == mid) and calling the recursive function with incorrect length (mid instead of mid-1). After these fixes the function looks like this:

```
public static long letsBegin(long reqd, long length){
    long mid = (length + 1)/2;
    if(length <= 3){
        return reqd;
    } else{
        if(reqd > mid){
            reqd = reqd - 2*(reqd-mid);
            switcher();     //Switcher stores if the value is switched
            return letsBegin(reqd, mid-1);
        } else if(reqd < mid) {
            return letsBegin(reqd, mid-1);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the code is more complicated than necessary. Try using the following recurrence relation instead:

```
T(n, k) = T(n, k-1)            if n < 2^{k-1}
        = 0                    if n = 2^{k-1}
        = 1 - T(2^k-n, k-1)    otherwise
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily done with recursion, the number of elements in k-th sequence is `2^(k+1)-1`:

```
static int foo(long n, int k) { //n-th element (indexed from 0) in k-th sequence
    long length = (2L << k) - 1; // computes 2^(k+1)-1
    if(n >= length) return -1; // prevent invalid inputs
    if(n == length/2) return 0; // middle point
    if(n < length/2) return foo(n, k-1); //left half
    return 1 - foo(length - n - 1, k-1); //right half
}
```

In the last recursive call, you both flip the array and the return value.

**EDIT:**

Be sure to use `(2L << k)` and not `(2 << k)` otherwise this will cause overflow and may lead to endless recursion.

Comment: Recursion is causing stack overflow for large inputs :-/

Comment: @Rockstar how comes? You said you will have most 50 sequences. Note that at 63 sequences the position could no longer fit into `long` and you would need to use `BigInteger` or something to represent the position. Also this method allocates little space on stack, you would need at least thousands of recursive calls on a regular computer to cause any problems.

Comment: Yes, it is at most 50 sequence, with no. of elements 1125899906842623 , for input k = 50, n=1125899906842622 program crashes with stack overflow at  `if(n < length/2) return foo(n, k-1);`

Comment: My fail, `(2 << k)` causes integer overflow, I'll edit the answer in a minute,

Comment: Thanks, it got fixed. But now it fails off Exceeding time limit >2sec :-/